# How to create a function that only exists for a particular template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a generic `Matrix` class. I have SSE-optimized matrix multiplication functions for when I'm dealing with a matrix of `Float` values. Currently, my methodology includes a function named "doSSE_mulMM" which does a matrix by matrix multiplication including a couple of checks, but which is only relevant for `Matrix<Float>` (it partly exists because I make a check for SSE capability in the code and move to a less efficient multiplication if SSE is not available).

For the version of GCC that our build server is running, I get this error:

> `error: specialization of ‘MTI::Matrix<float>& MTI::Matrix<BT>::doSSE_MulMM(const MTI::Matrix<float>&, const MTI::Matrix<float>&, bool) [with BT = float]’ after instantiation`

The same code compiles fine in Visual Studio and in the older version of GCC on our Linux host.

I can't provide the full code, but these are the signatures of the functions:

**Matrix.h**

```
template <class BT> 
class Matrix {
    ....
    Matrix<Float>&  doSSE_MulMM      (const Matrix<Float>& mat1, const Matrix<Float>& mat2, bool softmax);
    ....
}
```

**Matrix.cpp**

```
template <> 
Matrix<Float>&  Matrix<Float>::doSSE_MulMM (const Matrix<Float>& mat1, 
                                 const Matrix<Float>& mat2,
                                 bool softmax) {
    ....
}
```

The function of `doSSE_MulMM` only really makes sense for Float matrices, but I would much prefer making it a member function because it operates on private data members of the Matrix. Is there a good way of specializing the function to only exist in one specialization of the Matrix class? I suppose I could introduce a general version that raises an exception for the other data types, but that seems messy.

Comment: And how would the generic algorithm on Matrix<T> know that it can or cannot use said function?

Comment: The Float specialization of the regular mulMM function (and mulMT, mulTM, and mulTT) is the one that calls the specializaed version. I knew I forgot to mention a step...

Comment: Do you have an explicit specialization declaration of `Matrix<Float>::doSSE_MulMM` in your header file?

Comment: Other than what's above in Matrix.h, no.

Comment: Then how is the compiler supposed to know of this specialization? You need something like `template<> Matrix<Float>& Matrix<Float>::doSSE_MulMM(/*params*/);` in your header file, otherwise the compiler will try to instantiate this member function when used (and will not find the definition in other TUs but `Matrix.cpp`).

Comment: I think the way to go is using SFINAE and `enable_if` idioms.

Comment: Do you have a non-SSE mulmm function for all other instantiations?

Comment: @yzt: Most probably not. SFINAE is trendy, but not the solution for everything

Comment: You can opt to not have a differently named function for SSE and use tag dispatching to an internal implementation. The tag can be template parameter of Matrix.

Comment: @DyP:
Ideally, I'd like the function to simply not be specialized, i.e. if you use Matrix<Int>, you have the standard array of X functions. If you use Matrix<Float>, you have those X functions, some of which access doSSE_mulMM, which is essentially a helper function.

Comment: To me this sounds like a job for explicit specialization. But it's not obvious from the code you provided *what* should be explicitly specialized. I guess using inheritance and specializing the base class (which contains the implementations of the `MulMM` functions) might be appropriate.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:
Yes. I have the legacy code version and the SSE specialization. in separate non-Public functions. When mulMM (or mulMT, etc) get called, in the Float specialization of the class, they determine whether there is SSE functionality and decide whether to call the SSE or non-SSE version. That part works fine, and I could probably duplicate the code in doSSE_mulMM in each of those specializations, but I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like it's not a widely known feature, but you can specialize non-template member functions of class templates (that's what you tried to do).

As I've written in the comments, you just have to tell the compiler *that there's such a specialization available in another TU* so that it doesn't try to instantiate the function from the template.

*Matrix.hpp*

```
#include <iostream>

template < typename T >
struct Matrix
{
    void multiply()
    {
        std::cout << "non-specialized" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <>
void Matrix<float>::multiply();
```

*Matrix.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.hpp"

template <>
void Matrix<float>::multiply();
{
    std::cout << "specialized for float" << std::endl;
}
```

*some_other.cpp*

```
#include "Matrix.hpp"

int main()
{
    Matrix<int>{}.multiply();
    Matrix<float>{}.multiply();
}
```

The relevant passage in the Standard may be [temp.inst]/2:

> Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or **explicitly specialized**, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist; [...]

That is, you need the declaration `template <> void Matrix<float>::multiply();` to prevent instantiation. If instantiation is prevented, then there's no definition of `void Matrix<float>::multiply()` other than the explicit specialization, so the ODR is not violated.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=dc3db004e3)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to have the function exist for only one type would be CRTP, and specialize there.  The CRTP gives you access to the full type at the point where you implement the function, and the specialization lets you have the function only exist for certain types.

Here is a toy example:

```
template<typename D, typename T>
struct foo_for_float {};
template<typename D>
struct foo_for_float<D, float> {
  D* self() {
    static_assert( std::is_base< foo_for_float<D, float>, D >::value, "CRTP error" );
    return static_cast<D*>(this);
  }
  D const* self() const {
    static_assert( std::is_base< foo_for_float<D, float>, D >::value, "CRTP error" );
    return static_cast<D const*>(this);
  }
  void foo() { // const if you want to
    // use self() in this method instead of this
  }
};
// The usual CRTP magic "pass my own type to my parent":
template<typename T>
struct test : foo_for_float<test<T>, T> {
  void bar() {}
}
int main() {
  test<int> a;
  test<float> b;
  a.bar(); // valid
  b.bar(); // valid
  b.foo(); // valid
  a.foo(); // not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach based on SFINAE:

```
// matrix.h
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct matrix {

    // This is active only for U == T == float.
    // Otherwise, it does not participate in overload resolution.
    // Essentially this declaration is equivalent to:
    // matrix<float>& multiply(const matrix<float>& other);
    template <typename U>
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<U, T>::value &&
        std::is_same<U, float>::value,
        matrix&
    >::type
    multiply(const matrix<U>& other); // no definition here (convenient but not required)

    // This is active only for U == T != float
    // Otherwise, it does not participate in overload resolution.
    // Essentially this declaration is equivalent to:
    // matrix<T>& multiply(const matrix<T>& other); // for T != float
    template <typename U>
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<U, T>::value &&
        !std::is_same<U, float>::value,
        matrix&
    >::type
    multiply(const matrix<U>&) {
        std::cout << "generic multiplication\n";
        return *this;
    }

};
```

Then

```
// matrix.cpp
#include "matrix.h"

// The definition of
// matrix<float>& multiply(const matrix<float>& other);
template <>
template <>
matrix<float>&
matrix<float>::multiply<float>(const matrix<float>& other) {
    std::cout << "specific multiplication\n";
    return *this;
}
```

Finally, in client code:

```
#include "matrix.h"

int main() {

    matrix<int> mi1, mi2;
    mi1.multiply(mi2); // outputs 'generic multiplication'

    matrix<float> mf1, mf2;
    mf1.multiply(mf2); // outputs 'specific multiplication'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you need to specialize the full template Matrix.
You cannot specialize just one member function of a class template.
Then, you can add private members as much as you want.
If you are careful to fulfill the template contract in the specialization, generic algorithms on Matrix would not know the difference.

Comment: "You cannot specialize just one member function of a class template." Incorrect. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=596183b0de)